# Ember-Django Rest: Delete an authorised user account from an admin account

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-rest-framework-jwt

If the user accounts are authenticated using jwt authentication,
(backend - Django rest), how can I delete a user account from another account which is an admin account(superuser) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use django admin panel or create view

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)

    def delete(self, request, pk=None):
        user = get_object_or_404(User.objects, pk=pk)
        user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Then you have to link it with url containing pk parameter

Comment: So then I need not attach an authorisation header with the delete request from the front end POST request right?

Comment: Yep, exactly. If i helped you, please remember about up vote and marking as correct.